# Ellipsoidal movement easing equation

Tags: javascript, animation, easing

I want to simulate a elipsoidal movement of an object with easing equations, more specificly like a spinning top, but i cannot get an easing equation that helps me to do that, can anyone knows one?

i am using html/js, but no matter if is in another language, or maybe could made one here, i'll keep searching for a method, while i'll wait your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ellipse is parameterized by the equation:

```
var x = Math.cos(t) * smja;
var y = Math.sin(t) * smna;
```

Where `smja` and `smna` are the semi-major and semi-minor axes respectively.  Run t between 0 and 2π and (x, y) will describe an ellipse.